# Node anchor too far away from node text

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node, bounding-box, anchor

I'm using a loop to write several labels for line intersections, but perhaps for reasons of scale or something the labels are a bit too far away from the intersections. I can't fix each manually since I'm using a loop, and adding a fixed correction means errors propagate through the loop and the last labels are completely off.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,1) -- (2,1);
\draw (1,0) -- (1,2);

\node [anchor=north west] at (1,1) {Some text};
\node [anchor=north east] at (1.13,1.13) {Some text}; % Manual fix applied

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's my (extreme) MWE, and my actual application.

[image: MWE example]
[image: Example image]

I'm wondering if there's a way to move the anchor so that it's slightly within the text bounding box or something.

Comment: Sorry, but: `Unknown function 'calculation' (in 'calculation involving 1').` ... Would you mind post a compilable minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Agree wasn't a well-formatted question. Improved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `inner sep` with even negative values to shift the text of the node while keeping the anchor. Alternatively, use `outer sep` which would keep the padding to the text, in case you use borders.

Use `inner xsep` or `inner ysep` (or `outer xsep` or `outer ysep`) if you only want to apply this shift horizontally or vertically.

I am unsure if this can be used in your case, though.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,1) -- (2,1);
\draw (1,0) -- (1,2);

\node [anchor=south east, outer xsep=-10pt, draw=red] at (1,1) {Some text};

\node [anchor=north west, inner sep=-5pt] at (1,1) {Some text};

\node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at (1,1) {Some text}; % Now (almost) overlapping with the following node
\node [anchor=north east] at (1.13,1.13) {Some text}; % Manual fix applied
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]